# Unresolve a typescript import?

Tags: angular, typescript, types, node-modules

In my node_modules, I have a package that includes this import:
import { x } from 'node_modules/@types/openfin/_v2/main';

I am getting "cannot find module 'node_modules/@types/openfin/_v2/main' or its corresponding type declarations".

Now, what *does* work is both '../../../../../node_modules/@types/openfin/_v2/main' and 'openfin/_v2/main'. I believe the latter is used more commonly (no need to state node_modules/@types if you resolve the paths correctly). However, I'm stuck with this path that starts with node_modules/@types because I have no control over the npm package itself. (Even if I change it locally, it will reinstall node modules in the pipeline). How would I solve this without touching the package itself? By unresolving a path? Would that mess with my other packages that are working correctly?

Any help is appreciated! Already combed through many pages, including this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50722

Answer (score 0):

so I was able to resolve this by reaching out to the package owner and asking them to give me a version using 'openfin/_v2/main' as the import. If anyone has an answer that fiddles with local config settings instead of the package though, it might be helpful for future googlers! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@types/openfin is no longer maintained, check out [@openfin/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openfin/core) instead!